# do we need to close elasticsearch node after the every search request

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I want to know: do we have to call `node.close()` every time when we are done with our querying/searching process or just `client.close()` is fine? Here is my code:

```
val node =nodeBuilder().client(true).node()
val client =node.client()
val query = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(fieldName.toString(), q).fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO)//user can make 2 typo mistakes

val response = client.prepareSearch("arteciatedb")
      .setTypes("readOnlyAdmin")
      .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
      .addFields("uuid","FirstName","LastName","Email","SecondryEmail","UserStatus","_source")
      .setQuery(query)
      .execute()
      .actionGet()


 val hits = response.getHits

 totalHits=hits.getTotalHits
log.info("total search result {}",)   
client.close()
node.close()
```

I am running this code frequently; so, after `node.close()`, the next time I execute this code, it starts up the node again (causing delays in search response), which is not desired. I want to know if `node.close()` is the right thing to do when we need to call this searching code frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no, you can reuse the same client over time without trouble. `close()` should be used on shutdown only. Moreover, frequently starting and stopping one or more node clients creates unnecessary noise across the cluster.

Note that using `nodeBuilder().client(true).node()`, you are creating a node, that will join the ES cluster. If you just want a client and not a node, you should use `TransportClient` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html).

Comment: do  we also don't need to close the client as well ?

Comment: Yes same thing as node client