# Elasticsearch js client.close()

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticjs

I'm using elasticsearch client library on NodeJS, and I'm trying to understand if and when to use the `client.close()`method.
I'm using the same client in my entire application, and once in a while I'm doing some search on ES.

I was wondering first what does the `client.close` method do? As the communication with ES is in HTTP, I'm not really sure what to expect to happen, and couldn't find any documentation about it..

Secondly, should I close do connection after each search, or only on shutdown?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [do we need to close elasticsearch node after the every search request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064511/do-we-need-to-close-elasticsearch-node-after-the-every-search-request)

Comment: @nimeresam No, since this answer refers to the Java client, and not JavaScript.

Comment: It's in different language, but it has the same functionality!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that you use `elasticsearch` through your application, but it is a good practice to close the connection when you are shutting down the `Nodejs` instance. For example, while you shut down your server (NodeJS instance), you allow it to gracefully shut down. In that graceful shutdown process, you close your MongoDB connections (or any other DB connections for that matter) and ES connections etc. Some thing like this

```
server.close(() => {
        console.log('Gracefully shutting down');
        mongoDB.close()
        elasticsearch.close()    <==== this is what you want
        process.exit(0);
    });
```

Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003870/how-do-i-shut-down-my-express-server-gracefully-when-its-process-is-killed) that discusses how to shutdown NodeJS gracefully